# Spring Kafka RetryableTopic Many attempts

Tags: spring-kafka

I am using spring-kafka RetryableTopic for non-blocking retries with a fixed BackOff and [a single retry topic](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#single-topic-fixed-delay-retries).

I noticed that if I use more than 127 attempts the retry never stops and also if I use this header:

```
@Header(name = RetryTopicHeaders.DEFAULT_HEADER_ATTEMPTS, required = false) int attempt
```

It overflows to 0 after 127.

I couldn't find any limit for max_retries in spring-kafka documentation, but in the [source code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/blob/387d435e31d99c469a023700e52fd766b3e673b2/spring-kafka/src/main/java/org/springframework/kafka/retrytopic/DeadLetterPublishingRecovererFactory.java#L192) I see that it takes only first byte.

Is it a bug or feature? Are there plans to support max_attempts more than 127?

Answer (score 0):

Please, raise a GH issue against `spring-kafka` project.

The bug is here in the `DeadLetterPublishingRecovererFactory`:

```
private int getAttempts(ConsumerRecord<?, ?> consumerRecord) {
    Header header = consumerRecord.headers().lastHeader(RetryTopicHeaders.DEFAULT_HEADER_ATTEMPTS);
    return header != null
            ? header.value()[0]
            : 1;
}
```

The `header.value()` is a `byte[]` array from the:

```
headers.add(RetryTopicHeaders.DEFAULT_HEADER_ATTEMPTS,
            BigInteger.valueOf(attempts + 1).toByteArray());
```

But that `[0]` takes really only one byte from the array and cast it to `int`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Artem, but the "submit new issue" button is disabled for me in GH spring-kafka project. And also they explicitely say: ```STOP!! Please ask questions about how to use something, or to understand why something isn't
working as you expect it to, on Stack Overflow using the spring-kafka tag.```

Comment: Well, you asked  - I confirm that it is a bug, so time to raise an issue and move on. Unfortunately there is no workaround for your use-case. You can submit an issue when you add some content into that ticket form.

Comment: Thank you, done: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/2003